C# JSON deserialize array of regex patterns
I have an array of regex patterns stored in a single field in a db in a JSON-like format. Here is an example how this looks: ["^.*\/Car($|\/$|\?|\/\?)"]

I am trying to fetch this value and convert it into a string[] object using Newtonsoft.Json. Whenever I try to deserialize the string, it throws a Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderExeption.
Here is the code which I try it with:
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //working example
    string patterns = @"[""^.*\/Car""]";
    var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(patterns);
    Console.WriteLine(x.First()); //outputs ^.*/Car

    //non-working example
    patterns = @"[""^.*\/Car\?""]";
    x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(patterns); //throws Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Bad JSON escape sequence: \?. Path '', line 1, position 12.'
    Console.WriteLine(x.First());

    //non-working example
    patterns = @"[""^.*\/Car\?""]"; //actually redundant
    x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(JsonEncodedText.Encode(patterns).ToString()); //throws Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: \. Path '', line 1, position 2.'
    Console.WriteLine(x.First());

    //working example
    patterns = @"[""^.*\/Car\\?""]";
    x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(patterns); //outputs .*/Car\?
    Console.WriteLine(x.First());

    //what I ultimately would need to work
    //Regex pattern ^.*\/Car($|\/$|\?|\/\?)
    patterns = @"[""^.*\/Car($|\/$|\?|\/\?)""]";
    x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(patterns); //throws Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
    Console.WriteLine(x.First());
}

As you can see, the escaped question mark (\?) in the regex pattern is causing the problem. Only when I escape the backslash (\\?) the deserialization is working as expected (like in the 4th example).
This led me to look for an escaping function but so far I didn't find any working one. I tried to use JsonEncodedText.Encode(), but unfortunately that doesn't help either. Also escaping patterns using Regex.Escape(patterns) prior to deserialization throws a Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderExeption.
Does anybody know how I need to escape the string in order to be able to deserialize it to a string[] or List<string> object?
I also thought maybe the pattern array isn't stored correctly in the DB in the first place, but unfortunately I am very limited in the ability to influence the way in which the value is stored.

Fundamentally the problem is that your serialized string is "JSON-like", and not actually JSON. In JSON, backslashes inside strings have a special meaning. I think you need to understand the exact syntax of your "JSON-like" strings, e.g. how a regex which contains a quote is serialized. Based on that knowledge, you can come up with a way to either parse it directly into an array, or transform it into a valid JSON string

Just after I posted the question I realized that when I double the backslashes everything works fine:
x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(patterns.Replace("\\", "\\\\"));


Do make sure that this works correctly when the regex contains a quote character ". If that gets serialized as e.g. ["foo\"bar"], then your code above won't work correctly

Rather than using Replace() to manually create properly escaped JSON it would be better to serialize the patterns strings to JSON like so:  var pattern = @"""^.*\/Car"""; var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new [] { pattern }); var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>( json );
